# Screen Scraping with nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a full stack ruby developer.I am trying to scrape to the data from the website and i am successfully able to get the data.But the problem is that next time when i fetched the data i just want to fetch only new data the i don't want to overwrite all the the data in the database.
I just want to add new record which added recently.But i am not able to find any solution for that how to do it with minimum queries and minimum code.

Here is my code which i am using for scrapping:

```
   client = Mechanize.new
         index_page = client.get('https://www.google.com/')
         document_page_index = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse(index_page.body)
         page_no_merchant = document_page_index.css('.pagination.pagination-centered ul li:nth-last-child(2) a').text.to_i
         1.upto(page_no_merchant) do |page_number|
             client.get("https://www.google.com/buy-gift-cards?page=#{page_number}") do |page|
                 document = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse(page.body)


                 document.css('.product-source').each do |item|
                    merchant_name= item.children.css('.name').text.gsub("Gift Cards", "")
                     puts merchant_name
                     href = item.css('a').first.attr('href')
                     puts href
                     image_url=item.children.css('.img img').attr('data-src').text.strip
                     puts image_url

                      image_url=URI.parse(image_url)
                      @merchant=Merchant.create!(name: merchant_name , image_url:image_url)
                     first_page = client.get("https://www.google.com#{href}")
                     document_page = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse(first_page.body)
                     page_no = document_page.css('.pagination.pagination-centered ul li:nth-last-child(2) a').text.to_i

                     1.upto(page_no) do |page_number_giftcard|
                       type1=[]
                         card_page = client.get("https://www.google.com#{href}?page=#{page_number_giftcard}")
                         document_page = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse(card_page.body)
                         document_page.xpath('//table/tbody/tr[@class="toggle-details"]').collect do |row|



                           row.at("td[2] ul").children.each do |typeli|
                           type = typeli.text.strip if typeli.text.strip.length != 0
                           type1 << type if typeli.text.strip.length != 0
                           end

                             value = row.at('td[3]').text.strip
                             value = value.to_s.tr('$', '').to_f
                             puts value

                             per_discount = row.at('td[4]').text.strip
                             per_discount = per_discount.to_s.tr('%', '').to_f
                             puts per_discount

                             final_price = row.at('td[5] strong').text.strip
                             final_price = final_price.to_s.tr('$', '').to_f
                             puts final_price
                             puts '******************************'
                               @giftcard=Giftcard.create(card_type:1, card_value:value, per_off:per_discount, card_price: final_price, merchant_id: @merchant.id)
                         end
                           @giftcard.update_attribute()
                     end
                 end
             end
         end
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are saving all data, by doing this.

`@merchant=Merchant.create!(name: merchant_name , image_url:image_url)`

You can try something like `find_or_create_by`.

`@merchant=Merchant.find_or_create_by(name: merchant_name , image_url:image_url)`

http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create
http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by

Comment: can't quote URI::HTTPS

Comment: it's showing the error for the line @merchant=Merchant.find_or_create_by(name: merchant_name , image_url:image_url)

Comment: can you help me to find the attribute of tr which is used in the example

Comment: do you have any idea about fetching table tr data id from document_page.xpath('//table/tbody/tr[@class="toggle-details"]').collect do |row|



                           row.at("td[2] ul").children.each do |typeli|
                           type = typeli.text.strip if typeli.text.strip.length != 0
                           type1 << type if typeli.text.strip.length != 0
                           end

                             value = row.at('td[3]').text.strip